# Looping through array of strings - stay on last string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function which loops through a list of strings every 5 seconds. I would like it to stay on the last string after finishing the loop.
What do I need to change here?

```
window.specialWorkBoxStyleOverride = function(workBox) {
    var statusTextBox = $("<div class = 'status-description-box'></div>");
    $(workBox).append(statusTextBox);
    var statusTexts = ["Checking", "Updating", "Processing", "Saving"];
    var idx = 0;
    var updateStatus = function() {
        statusTextBox.text(statusTexts[idx]);
        idx = (idx + 1) % statusTexts.length;
        setTimeout(updateStatus, 5000);
    };
    updateStatus();
};
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your code always calls `setTimeout`, so it will loop forever. Checking whether you've reached the end of your list should be sufficient to stop this (and means you don't need the modular arithmetic any more):

```
var updateStatus = function() {
    statusTextBox.text(statusTexts[idx]);
    idx++;
    if (idx < statusTexts.length) { 
        setTimeout(updateStatus, 5000);
    }
};
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks so much, Alex.